# Getting Error : lvalue required while trying to implement a Jagged Array in C

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue, jagged-arrays, double-pointer

I am trying to implement the concept of Jagged Array while learning the C language.

My code goes below :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r,**a,n,i,j,*ptr;
    do {
        printf("Enter no. of Rows : ");
        scanf("%d",&r);
        if(r<0)
            printf("\nPlease enter a positive value\n\n");
    } while(r<0);
    a = (int**)malloc(r * sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        do {
            printf("Enter no. of elements in row %d : ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&n);
            if(n<0)
                printf("\nPlease enter a positive value\n\n");
        } while(n<0);
        *(a+i) = (int*)malloc((n+1) * sizeof(int));
        printf("\n");
        printf("Input Row %d elements : ",i+1);
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            scanf("%d",&(*(*(a+i)+j)));
        (*(a+i))+j = NULL;
    }
    printf("\n\nYou entered :-\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++) {
        for(j=0; (*(a+i))+j; j++)
            printf("%d\t",*(*(a+i)+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        free(*(a+i));
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation this gives an Error :-

> 26   error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

basically for this line of code where I get the value for each pointer element & assign the last pointer element in each row to null :-

```
printf("Input Row %d elements : ",i+1);
for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    scanf("%d",&(*(*(a+i)+j)));
(*(a+i))+j = NULL;
```

Basically the concept for this Jagged Array is that it inputs the number of rows and then the number of elements in each row seperately and inputs that many elements.

I create a dynamic array of (n+1) * sizeof(int) in each row pointer where n is the number of elements in that row. The (n+1)th element is for storing a null pointer so that while displaying the array we can get where to break out to the next row.

Sorry for posting the whole code but since I don't know where the problem could arise from in the code so I have posted the whole code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` has a type `int**` (pointer to a pointer). `(a+i)` has the same type, `*(a + i)` is a pointer, `*(a + i) +j` is a pointer as well. The problem is you're trying to assign to a temporary object, which was created by the '+' operator. In fact, you're asking the compilator to solve an equation for you and then modify `*(a + i)`, as it's the only value in your expression that is stored in memory.

The only thing you can do it assign either to `*(a+i)` (and therefore set location of the row) or to `*(*(a+i)+j)` (and set value of a particular element in the row), or to `a` itself (and set location of pointers to rows).

This is not a Java and int doesn't have a NULL value. NULL in C is a macro which expands to zero, which can be casted to a null pointer afterwards.

So, allocation of (n+1) elements is useless if user types zero. You can, however, change `a`'s type to `int***` and store in each cell either pointer to a single `int` or NULL. However, this is a greate overhead and I wouldn't do this. You'd better store length of each row as its first element.

And, as Medinoc suggested, use `[]` instead of asterisks and pluses. `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)`.

Comment: So it would not be possible to set the pointer to NULL and use this concept. Please confirm on this..

Comment: Yes, it's impossible. As I mentioned, the only way to do something like this is to store ints separately and store pointers in array. If you don't mind, please mark the best answer as answer to your question, if you think it's exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The way parentheses are set in `(*(a+i))+j` causes it to be an rvalue. Likely a typo.

Can't you just use the simpler `a[i][j]` syntax? Parenthesis errors are less likely this way.

Comment: Basically I want to set the pointer to the (i,j)th element of the Array to null, and wouldn't a[i][j] point to the value of the (i,j)th element.

Comment: `&a[i][j]` (or failing that, `&(a[i][j])`) would.